# AWS ApiGateway Lambda Proxy access Authorizer

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, aws-api-gateway, amazon-cognito

I´m using an Lambda Proxy and a Cognito User Pool Authorizer in my ApiGateway. In the Lambda function I can access the path etc. variables via the event object. In addition to that I want to access the claims of the authenticated user. In the documentation it is written, that I should use:

`context.authorizer.claims.property`

But I authorizer is null so I get

`Cannot read property 'claims' of undefined`

Anyone with an idea?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are referring to [this part of the documentation](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/apigateway/latest/developerguide/apigateway-integrate-with-cognito.html), `$context.authorizer.claims` is part of the mapping template of the integration. It is not related to the `context` argument of the handler.

Using `Lambda Proxy integration`, you are using the `passthrough mapping template`. I̶t̶ ̶s̶e̶e̶m̶s̶ ̶w̶h̶a̶t̶ ̶i̶t̶ ̶d̶o̶e̶s̶ ̶n̶o̶t̶ ̶i̶n̶c̶l̶u̶d̶e̶ ̶w̶h̶a̶t̶ ̶y̶o̶u̶ ̶a̶r̶e̶ ̶l̶o̶o̶k̶i̶n̶g̶ ̶f̶o̶r̶ (see edit). You'll probably have to disable `Lambda Proxy integration` and use something like this in the mapping template:

```
{
    "identity" : {
        "sub" : "$context.authorizer.claims.sub",
        "email" : "$context.authorizer.claims.email"
    }
}
```

The mapping template "build" the `event` parameter of the Lambda. So you will be able to access to the parts of your claim via the `event` parameter.

```
exports.handler = (event, context, callback) => {
    // TODO implement
    callback(null, event.identity.email);
};
```

---

Note that I slightly modified the documentation example to avoid another confusion about what `context` can be:

- the mapping template variable in API Gateway
- the second argument of a handler in Lambda
- a key of the `event` argument in some examples of the documentation  <= I renamed it `identity`

---

**Edit**

As pointed out by *doorstuck*, [the information is available using the proxy integration](https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/compute/authorizing-access-through-a-proxy-resource-to-amazon-api-gateway-and-aws-lambda-using-amazon-cognito-user-pools/)

Comment: Thanks for your detailed answer. When I disable the Proxy Integration I will not be able to access properties like path, queryString etc.?

Comment: You will be able to do it via the mapping template too. I would suggest to select the "Method Requet passthrough" template and complete it with what you need.

Comment: Works! Thank you ;)

Comment: @SnowMax @Alexis N-o Seems like a lot of work. You can access the authorizer claims in `event.requestContext.authorizer.claims` with Lambda Proxy Integration.

Answer (score 7):

The accepted answer will work but it is not needed. When using Lambda Proxy Integration you can access the authorizer claims at:

```
event.requestContext.authorizer.claims
```

You can try to `console.log(event);` and see the information you get out of a Lambda Proxy Integration in CloudWatch Logs.

Comment: Nice, the "Method Requet passthrough" does not contain it when *not* using  the Lambda Proxy Integration. I thought the same mapping template would be used.

Comment: I would emphasize the conosle.log event or authorizer object, you might not have claims object and the properties you are looking for might be under authorizer

Answer (score 0):

Ensure you are sending the "**Identity Token**" as the Authorization header instead of the "**Access Token**".

[Documentation for Identity Token](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/apigateway/latest/developerguide/apigateway-integrate-with-cognito.html)

For example, I am using Amplify and was getting the access token with:

```
userSession.getAccessToken().getJwtToken() // Wrong
```

instead of

```
userSession.getIdToken().getJwtToken() // Correct
```