# Access authorizer from an AWS lambda function with proxy integration - Python

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, aws-api-gateway, amazon-cognito

[Derived from [AWS ApiGateway Lambda Proxy access Authorizer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42350118/aws-apigateway-lambda-proxy-access-authorizer) ]

I´m using an Lambda Proxy and a Cognito User Pool Authorizer in my ApiGateway. With node.js Lambda functions, it's possible access to have access to the authorizer (basically, get the user id, email and stuff) in `event.requestContext.authorizer.claims`.

But in Python, *there's no such object*. Exploring the `event` object and the `context` object shows there's nothing like `requestContext` or `authorizer`, just an `identity` object that contains Cognito Federated Identities information : for me, it's just `null`.

I haven't seen any mention of the `event.requestContext.authorizr.claims` in Python AWS-Lambda functions, and it would be a pain to

1. use federated identities instead
2. in API Gateway, set Authorization to `AWS_IAM` and turn on `Invoke with caller credential`
3. drop the proxy integration for a custom integration or
4. write the lambdas with node.js instead of python

Have you any idea if I'm missing something, if it's not implemented by AWS, if there's an easy workaround, or anything else ?

Thanks a lot for your help !

*Here's the context object in python aws-lambda function, in a dictionary-like form :*

```
"aws_request_id":"99XXXXf5-6XXe-1XX8-bXXf-5dXXXXXXXX50",
  "function_name":"test_DynamoDB",
  "function_version":"$LATEST",
  "invoked_function_arn":"arn:aws:lambda:eu-west-3:4XXXXXXXXXX0:function:test_DynamoDB",
  "log":"<bound method LambdaContext.log of <__main__.LambdaContext object at 0x7f07bcb21da0>>",
  "log_group_name":"/aws/lambda/test_DynamoDB",
  "log_stream_name":"2018/06/13/[$LATEST]76XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXf0",
  "memory_limit_in_mb":"128",
  "identity":{  
     "cognito_identity_id":null,
     "cognito_identity_pool_id":null
  },
  "client_context": None
```

#### Update

From https://stackoverflow.com/a/44039371/9936457 , it seems the same issue was in C# lambda functions and there's a workaround for it, using System.IO.Streams. Would this solution work in Python, with the right syntax ?

Comment: Can you pass the information you require using the body mapping template?

Comment: Yes it would be possible, but that would mean dropping the Proxy integration with API Gateway, which I would rather avoid!